# Getting error while adding spring security lib

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have found some solutions but they didn't worked for me. I added libraries to project but I am getting this error. I could reach security libraries from my controller classes. Any idea?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration     problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace     [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security] 
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]
```

This my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="test" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: what did you try? are using maven?

Comment: @fGo I am not using Maven.

Comment: @fGo I am Not using Maven. what is pom?

Comment: OK, so show us how you are building your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd` as your namespace instead.

Comment: still getting same error. I am using version 3.1.4 so i changed it to http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.4.xsd but this time i am getting "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.4.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>."

Answer (score 0):

to avoid

```
"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read
 schema document 'springframework.org/schema/security/…;, because 1)
 could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the
 root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>."
```

change `springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.4.xsd` to  `springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd`